# Why is jQuery not working with Bootstrap 4 alpha 6?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to use jQuery and it is giving me various errors. I tried shuffling different script tags around, but had no success. Here is some code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
 <style>
/*some css here*/
  </style>

        <!--a bunch of HTML here-->
      <script>
if(jQuery){
alert('yes');
}
    $(window).load(function(){
            $('.intro').fadeIn(500, function(){
                $(".welcomeSize").fadeIn(500);
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I get an error saying that jQuery is undefined. If I put the jquery CDN before my script, I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: a.indexOf is not a function
    at r.fn.init.r.fn.load (jquery.min.js:4)
    at newsite.html:129
```

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: remove bootstrap. you'll pretty quickly see that it is unrelated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is not related with bootstrap, you are adding jQuery dependent script before it's loaded. Add your script after jQuery and use `$(document).ready()`, `.load()` is deprecated. https://api.jquery.com/load-event/

```css
.intro{
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background: purple;
 display: none;
}
.welcomeSize{
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background: violet;
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JQuery+Bootstrap</title>
</head>
<body>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>

<div class="intro">
 
</div>
   <div class="welcomeSize">
    
   </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
if(jQuery){
console.log('yes');
}
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.intro').fadeIn(500, function(){
                $(".welcomeSize").fadeIn(500);
            });
        });
    </script> 
  </body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to import jquery before write any code using jquery so what you have to do is

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

// then your code goes here
```

the second thing for `Uncaught TypeError: a.indexOf is not a function`

you should use `$(window).on('load', function() { ... });`

instead of

```
$(window).load(function() { ... });
```

> load, .unload, and .error, deprecated since jQuery 1.8, are no more.
>   Use .on() to register listeners.

Answer (score -1):

Note that you've been using the jQuery commands before linking the script. The script tag which source(src) attribute is pointing to Google CDN must come before the jQuery command.

Comment: This post already has accepted answer. Dont need to add a dupe until unless your answer enhances the existing answer..