# JQuery $ not useable with Sufee

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I downloaded the [Sufee](https://github.com/puikinsh/sufee-admin-dashboard) template and which imports jquery:

```
  <script src="vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

AFTER that line I defined my own javascript - using with the if-else suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42661617/why-is-jquery-not-working-with-bootstrap-4-alpha-6/42661858):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(jQuery){
console.log('yes');

$(document).ready(function() {
  //launch cyclic calls
  setInterval(function(){
    alert('sdf');
  }, 1000);
});
```

In my Crome I get a 'yes' but I do not get the alert - instead I get the following error:

```
index.html:311 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you have multiple jQuery implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution: It seems that the template imports a main.js which uses:

```
$.noConflict();
```

so that I cannot use $ any more later on!