# How can I get and use a bootstrap modal parameter?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I call a modal with a link :

```
<a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#updateActionModal" data-id="42" >M</a>
```

My goal is to use the parameter "data-id" inside my modal. Here is the code of my modal :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="updateActionModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="updateActionModalTitle">Modifier une action</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        {{ form(updateForm) }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="javascript">
    $('#updateActionModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
  var actionId = button.data('id')
  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find(#updateActionModalTitle).text(actionId)
}
</script>
```

As you can see, I would like to replace here the modal's title id="updateActionModalTitle" by the data-id parameter (here, equal to "42"). But it doesn't work. When I clic on the link, my modal is called, but the title isn't updated.

Note that in the same file, I use :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Here is the explanation of my mistake... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42661617/why-is-jquery-not-working-with-bootstrap-4-alpha-6

Comment: Missing quotes for the `find()` selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you are not using bootstrap.css as per code posted by u, use it.

Look at the below snippet, there are also other ways to achieve your goal this is one of them.

Hope this will be useful.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#showModal').click(function(e){
    var btnVal = $(this).data('id');
    $('#btnVal').text(btnVal);
    $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="showModal" data-id="42" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  M
</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="btnVal"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```